# How can I get the number of occurrences in a SQL IN clause?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have four tables: `PAGE`, `USER`, `TAG`, and `PAGE-TAG`:

```
Table      | Fields
------------------------------------------
PAGE       | ID, CONTENT
TAG        | ID, NAME
USER       | ID, NAME    
PAGE-TAG   | ID, PAGE-ID, TAG-ID, USER-ID
```

And let's say I have four pages:

```
PAGE#1 'Content page 1' tagged with tag#1 by user1, tagged with tag#1 by user2 
PAGE#2 'Content page 2' tagged with tag#3 by user2, tagged by tag#1 by user2, tagged by tag#8 by user1  
PAGE#3 'Content page 3' tagged with tag#7 by user#1
PAGE#4 'Content page 4' tagged with tag#1 by user1, tagged with tag#8 by user1
```

I expect my query to look something like this:

```
select page.content ?
from page, page-tag 
where 
page.id = page-tag.pag-id 
and page-tag.tag-id in (1, 3, 8) 
order by ? desc
```

I would like to get output like this:

```
Content page 2, 3
Content page 4, 2
Content page 1, 1
```

---

Quoting Neall

> Your question is a bit confusing. Do you want to get the number of times each page has been tagged?

No

> The number of times each page has gotten each tag?

No

> The number of unique users that have tagged a page?

No

> The number of unique users that have tagged each page with each tag?

No

I want to know how many of the passed tags appear in a particular page, not just if any of the tags appear.

SQL IN works like an boolean operator OR. If a page was tagged with any value within the IN Clause then it returns true. I would like to know how many of the values inside of the IN clause return true.

Below i show, the output i expect:

```
page 1 | in (1,2)   -> 1

page 1 | in (1,2,3) -> 1

page 1 | in (1)     -> 1

page 1 | in (1,3,8) -> 1

page 2 | in (1,2)   -> 1

page 2 | in (1,2,3) -> 2

page 2 | in (1)     -> 1

page 2 | in (1,3,8) -> 3

page 4 | in (1,2,3) -> 1

page 4 | in (1,2,3) -> 1

page 4 | in (1)     -> 1

page 4 | in (1,3,8) -> 2
```

This will be the content of the page-tag table i mentioned before:

```
   id       page-id  tag-id  user-id  

    1       1        1       1 

    2       1        1       2 

    3       2        3       2 

    4       2        1       2 

    5       2        8       1 

    6       3        7       1 

    7       4        1       1 

    8       4        8       1
```

**@Kristof** does not exactly what i am searching for but thanks anyway.

**@Daren** If i execute you code i get the next error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'page-tag.tag-id' in 'having clause'
```

**@Eduardo Molteni** Your answer does not give the output in the question but:

```
Content page 2 8
Content page 4 8
content page 2 3
content page 1 1
content page 1 1
content page 2 1
cotnent page 4 1
```

**@Keith** I am using plain SQL not T-SQL and i am not familiar with T-SQL, so i do not know how your query translate to plain SQL.

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the key difference between this and kristof's answer is that you only want a count of 1 to show against page 1, because it has been tagged only with one tag from the set (even though two separate users both tagged it).

I would suggest this:

```
SELECT page.ID, page.content, count(*) AS uniquetags
FROM
   (  SELECT DISTINCT page.content, page.ID, page-tag.tag-id 
      FROM page INNER JOIN page-tag ON page.ID=page-tag.page-ID 
      WHERE page-tag.tag-id IN (1, 3, 8) 
   )
    GROUP BY page.ID
```

I don't have a SQL Server installation to check this, so apologies if there's a syntax mistake. But semantically I think this is what you need.

This may not give the output in descending order of number of tags, but try adding:

```
      ORDER BY uniquetags DESC
```

at the end. My uncertainty is whether you can use `ORDER BY` outside of grouping in SQL Server. If not, then you may need to nest the whole thing in another `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
select page.content, count(page-tag.tag-id) as tagcount
from page inner join page-tag on page-tag.page-id = page.id
group by page.content
having page-tag.tag-id in (1, 3, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

In T-Sql:

```
select count(distinct name)
from page-tag
where tag-id in (1, 3, 8)
```

This will give you a count of the number of different tag names for your list of ids

Answer (score 0):

Agree with **Neall**, bit confusing the question.
If you want the output listed in the question, the sql is as simple as:

```
select page.content, page-tag.tag-id
from page, page-tag 
where page.id = page-tag.pag-id 
and page-tag.tag-id in (1, 3, 8) 
order by page-tag.tag-id desc
```

But if you want the tagcount, **Daren** answered your question

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    page.content, 
    count(pageTag.tagID) as tagCount
from 
    page
    inner join pageTag on page.ID = pageTag.pageID
where 
    pageTag.tagID in (1, 3, 8) 
group by
    page.content
order by
    tagCount desc
```

That gives you the number of tags per each page; ordered by the higher number of tags

I hope I understood your question correctly

Answer (score 0):

Leigh Caldwell answer is correct, thanks man, but need to add an alias at least in MySQL. So the query will look like:

```
SELECT page.ID, page.content, count(*) AS uniquetags FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT page.content, page.ID, page-tag.tag-id FROM page INNER JOIN page-tag ON page.ID=page-tag.page-ID WHERE page-tag.tag-id IN (1, 3, 8) ) as page
    GROUP BY page.ID
order by uniquetags desc
```